# Swift:Line chart lineView.rightAxis.axisMinValue is not working

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I am using [danielgindi/Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my app.`lineView.leftAxis.axisMinValue = 0`
is working fine but `lineView.rightAxis.axisMinValue = 0` is not working. The right axis always starts from 1 as shown in fig.I am using Chart 2.And need to do alot in my projects to go to 3. What am i doing wrong here??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `lineView.xAxis.axisMinValue = 0` ? I believe right axis refers to a secondary y-axis, which it looks like you do not have enabled.